# Have bind9 wait until openvpn interface settles

Tags: ubuntu, bind, openvpn

I have OpenVPN AS started as an rc.d script. I want Bind9 to bind to a virtual network interface that OpenVPN sets up.

However only after the script terminates some virtual devices names `as0t0` and `as0t1`. Meanwhile, Bind9 (DNS server) is started and it can't bind to those interfaces since they don't exist at the time.

Changing LSB dependencies and Sxx numbers using update-rc.d didn't help, since the openvpn script finishes before actually bringing up the interfaces.

It seems that `/etc/if-up.d/bind9` exists exactly for this purpose, but apparently it does not run when the virtual network interfaces are started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script `/etc/if-up.d/bind9` is just running the command `rndc reconfig >/dev/null 2>&1 || true`.

It sure seems like you could adjust your OpenVPN server configuration to simply run that command after the daemon has started.  You probably want to do that by specifying an `--up` script.  You could add this to your OpenVPN configuration like this.

```
up /etc/network/if-up.d/bind9
script-security 2              # permit a script to called
```

On OpenVPN Access Server, those lines can be added through the Web UI. Go to Configuration -> Advanced VPN -> Server Config Directives.

Comment: To clarify, the bind9 is to be run on the server side of OpenVPN. I'm not sure where in OpenVPN configuration to add the lines you wrote. The thing is that the init.d script exits before the interface is actually up.

Comment: Yes, I understand that Bind is running, which is why that script in if-up.d is calling `rndc reconfig`, do re-configure it.  As for the how to configure OpenVPN AS.  See section 4.2.5.7 in the manual.